# Простой слайдер на чистом JavaScript

Tags: javascript

У кого-нибудь есть простой слайдер на чистом JavaScript? Поделитесь пожалуйста.
Пытаюсь сделать свой, но пока сложновато. Хочу взять за основу готовое решение и разобраться на нем.

```
var slide_left = document.getElementById('slide-left'),
slide_right = document.getElementById('slide-right'),
total_img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

slide_right.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);
function moveLeft(){
    slide_left.style.display = 'block';
}
```

полный код https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/srkxLkou/

Comment: Да что же в нем сложного? Есть переменная, хранит первоначальное значение. При клике влево или вправо делается инкремент или декреммент. Если достигается края и щелкается еще раз стрелка того же направления, то счетик сбрасывается..... всё..... если авто слайдер - то вешается `setInterval` к примеру

Comment: мой слайдер сейчас на этой стадии https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/srkxLkou/

из вашего комментария ничего не понятно

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Подправил ваш [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/srkxLkou/2/).

Направление мысли у вас было правильное. Нужно было только добавить оставшуюся логику для переключения картинок. Привожу код с комментариями к тому, что я добавил:

```
var slide_left = document.getElementById('slide-left'),
    slide_right = document.getElementById('slide-right'),
    total_img = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    idx = 0; // Индекс текущего слайда.

slide_right.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);
function moveLeft(){
    slide_left.style.display = 'block';
    total_img[idx].style.display = 'none'; // Скрываем текущий слайд
    total_img[++idx].style.display = 'block'; // Инкрементируем индекс и показываем следующий слайд
    if (idx === total_img.length - 1) { // Убираем "правую" стрелку, если справа слайдов больше нет
      slide_right.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

//Аналогично, только для левой стрелки
slide_left.addEventListener('click', moveRight);
function moveRight(){
    slide_right.style.display = 'block';
    total_img[idx].style.display = 'none';
    total_img[--idx].style.display = 'block';
    if (idx === 0) {
      slide_left.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое! все предельно понятно

Comment: я хочу добавить анимацию с помощью transition, чтобы изображения плавно сменяли друг друга. знаю как это добавить для `:hover`. но как применить это к изображению, если функция вызывается по клику на другой элемент? и еще вместо добавления стилей я сделала добавление классов, но теперь слайдер налево не работает. вот так https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/f4omfqsn/1/ . наверное надо как-то удалять класс?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, [вот](https://jsfiddle.net/f4omfqsn/2/). Удалять класс нужно с помощью `classList.remove()`. Там несколько хаков: `transform: translate(-50%, 0)` - двигаем картинку на 50% от своей ширины влево (убери и увидишь, зачем я это сделал). Анимацию я сделал через `left` и `position: absolute`, т.к. с `display` анимации не работают. Скорость картинок разная потому, что ширина их разная. Нужно либо все картинки одинаковой ширины делать, либо для каждой подбирать свой `left`. Обрати внимание, что скрол снизу появился. Нужно зафиксировать ширину слайдера и добавить `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: спасибо большое! анимацию я по другому представляю, но это я уже сама поразбираюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Для чего создавать велосипед, если его давно создали в интернете можно найти сотни слайдеров на чистом `JavaScript`. [Пример](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/61707/) или ищите по запросу - слайдер на чистом JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Слайдер на JavaScript.</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<style>
#main {
    position:relative;
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 660px;
    height:360px;
    background-color: silver;
    border: 5px solid grey;
    border-radius:15px;
}
#scr {
    margin:20px auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 320px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color: white;
    background-size:cover;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
}
button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 70px;
    font: 12pt arial,tahoma,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.left {
    left:5px;
}
.right {
    right:5px;
}
</style>
<script>
var slider = {
    slides:['ch01.jpg','ch02.jpg','ch03.jpg','ch04.jpg','ch05.jpg'],
    frame:0, // текущий кадр для отбражения - индекс картинки из массива
    set: function(image) { // установка нужного фона слайдеру
        document.getElementById("scr").style.backgroundImage = "url("+image+")";
    },
    init: function() { // запуск слайдера с картинкой с нулевым индексом
        this.set(this.slides[this.frame]);
    },
    left: function() { // крутим на один кадр влево
        this.frame--;
        if(this.frame < 0) this.frame = this.slides.length-1;
        this.set(this.slides[this.frame]);
    },
    right: function() { // крутим на один кадр вправо
        this.frame++;
        if(this.frame == this.slides.length) this.frame = 0;
        this.set(this.slides[this.frame]);      
    }
};
window.onload = function() { // запуск слайдера после загрузки документа
    slider.init();
    setInterval(function() { // ставим пятисекундный интервал для перелистывания картинок
        slider.right();
    },5000);
};
</script>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <button class="left" onclick="slider.left();"><</button>
    <div id="scr"></div>
    <button class="right" onclick="slider.right();">></button>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо. находила только с jquery

Comment: если я хочу картинки подключать из html я могу просто убрать этот код?  `slides:['ch01.jpg','ch02.jpg','ch03.jpg','ch04.jpg','ch05.jpg'],` 
надо что-то еще менять?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova  Если вам этот ответ был полезен поставьте галочку напротив ответа. Это слайдер очень простенький, если вам нужен более функциональный, нужно подключать библиотеку jquery и пользоваться каким-то плагином которых в интернете полно.

Comment: у меня не работает, или я что-то не так делаю. и это очень странный способ подключения изображений

Comment: Велосипед нужно повторить для того чтобы разобраться как это работает. Вас попросили помочь разобраться в коде, а не научить гуглом пользоваться. А если вы вставляете кусок непонятного кода только ради галочки, то лучше не отвечайте вообще.